Matching satellite, DEM and OSM images
I have a set of satellite GeoTIFF images (from https://xview2.org/) that I want to pair with DEM images from OpenTopography (https://portal.opentopography.org/raster?opentopoID=OTNED.012021.4269.3) and Open Street Map (downloaded from https://download.geofabrik.de/ and processed using Maperitive).
I extracted the coordinates of the satellite images with GDAL (using this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2926097) and used those coordinates to select the DEM and OSM images.
Although the DEM & OSM match almost perfectly to each other, they don't match to the satellite images whatsoever. For one thing, the satellite images have a dimension of 1024x1024, but the DEM and OSM images have dimension 1024x1180.
I am a beginner to working with GIS so I am completely stumped here as to what the problem is, or how I should even start to go about fixing it.

By 'match almost perfectly to each other,' do you mean you have verified them in a GIS application such as QGIS? Please check the coordinate systems of all three datasets and post them here.  You can use  https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html and https://gdal.org/programs/ogrinfo.html   for checking CRS of vector and raster respectively
